# Fullpage.js not scrolling on phone

Tags: jquery, iphone, scroll, fullpage.js

I have installed the jQuery plugin fullpage.js on a webpage I am working on, and it works fine on my computer, but the content on the 2nd section of the page is too large to fit on my phone's screen, and should be scrolling - but I cannot figure out how to do this. I won't pretend I know much about javascript, so I'm a bit at a loss, and the solution might be something simple.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Webpage in question:
http://romowind.com/testside/ - it's the front page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make use of the option `scrollOverflow` setting it to `true` and add the dependency `jquery.slimscroll.min.js` before you load the `jquery.fullpage.js` file as specified [at the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs).

The javascript `jquery.slimscroll.min.js` is located in the `vendors` folder once you download the plugin.

Make sure to use the last version of fullpage.js.

Your included files should be 4 (2 jquery libraries + fullpage js file + fullpage css file + slimscroll ) 
Something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
```

Then, your initialization should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.fullpage({
        slidesColor: ['#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff', '#fff'],
        anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
        scrollOverflow: true
    });
});
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for making such an awesome plugin! I *think* I understood what you meant, but somehow it still doesn't seem to work. I have all newest versions of the files, as far as I can see, and included all 5 of them. I added the scrollOverflow: true option, but it only seemed to center my top-menu, it didn't make the page scrollable on my phone. I have a feeling I'm missing something simple, I just can't find it.

Comment: Can you give us the URL to check it? Or if not, reproduce the problem in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: The scroll is not working as expected either in the desktop website. The scroll bar should be grey. Try removing the two scripts you have at the end of the last section. They should be in the header of the site.

Comment: After looking at your code a bit more. There's something weird with your `id="logoarea"` element. Removing all the element makes the scroll to work properly on desktop devices. You should check it.

Comment: And probably will solve the problem you are having on mobile devices.

Comment: That did do the trick! I had tried to disable it before also, but at that point I didn't have the scrolloverflow-part. Now with that turned on and the logo-plugin turned off, the scroll works, finally. Thank you very very much for your help!

Comment: @Skymone your welcome! You should accept the answer as valid by the way! :)